# HR performance management system

Tags: web-apps, database, data-analysis, performance-analysis, google-apps

I am looking for software similar to [workday](http://www.workday.com/) or [successfactors](http://www.successfactors.com/en_us.html) for HR performance management system. But the examples I mentioned are a bit expensive. The main purpose of the software is to monitor employee performance and compensation.

*For example let us consider an accountant at one of our units. He needs to submit a report everyday at 5pm. The minute he submits his report on time he gets 1 point for that day. And I preset his working days and lets assume, out of 22 working days, he submits on time on 20 days.*

*There are some weekly and monthly reports that will be due and some of them might be worth 5 points or some other value. And at the end of the month he scores 126/140. So his rating for the month is 9. And some of the 9-pointers may be entitled to a bonus, based on some factors.*

Parts of this data will entered into a different ERP. The software should have a configuration to pull data using an API.

I want to find software for under $2000/year. The solution I am looking for is for a non-profit organization with 1200 employees, so it is hard to maintain quality and effective implementation without a performance management system.

**Requirements:**

- monitor employee performance and compensation
- free (or not expensive)
- data entry to a different ERP
- configuration to pull data using an API
- the software should be able to deal with high number of users

Answer (score 1):

[CiviHR](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civihr) is an extension to [CiviCRM](http://civicrm.org), an open source, free CRM. CiviHR would be an answer to a HR tool requirements but as far as I know, there isn't performance specific functionality - but it has a lot of regular features of HR software, to mention a few:

- People (Paid & Unpaid) - a directory listing of the people who work
  for an organisation - showing names and photographs
- Personal Contact, work details, identification, emergency contacts
- Medical & Disability
- Visas & Work Permits
- Job Positions & Job Roles
- Skills & Qualification
- Education & Employment
- Simple Remuneration Recording
- Recording of Leave and Absence
- Workflows to manage Joining, Probation and Exiting
- Recruitment with an online job application process

Because the staff that is submitting reports needs to somehow authenticate against the system (so that the system knows which person submitted the report), I would design a system based on Drupal and CiviCRM combination, letting Drupal take care of user authentication and calculating points for performance (for creating nodes "Reports" within specific timeframes) while CiviCRM with CiviHR would take care of all remaining HR requirements. Drupal and CiviCRM are tightly integrated, which is also a great plus when it comes to creating reports that combine all the information from both systems.

Also, because CiviHR is an open source tool that is being constantly improved, it is possible to contact creators and ask for the piece you are looking for to be developed/added to that extension. Of course, that may be a paid work but it may still be cheaper than paying for a license of a proprietary software.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to read [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tools-for-managing-employee-performance-reviews/) a while ago, which I found informative. You might focus on the open source version of OrangeHRM and on WaypointHR regarding your limitation on out of pocket costs.